# Can I run scripts on startup on rooted Galaxy Note 3?

Tags: boot, shell, scripts, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I want to be able to run a shell command (e.g. `mount`) on startup on my Galaxy Note 3 (stock rooted Android 4.3)

Typically on Linux that'd be done using `/etc/init.d` but **I don't have that directory** on my Note 3.

What's the best approach to running a shell script on startup/boot on Galaxy Note 3?

Comment: Note: this is NOT a dupe of [another](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/how-can-i-run-a-script-on-boot?rq=1) - the answers there are not applicable to Note3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [ScriptManager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/script-manager-smanager/os.tools.scriptmanager):

> Manage and execute shell scripts and programs in file system.
>   All executions run over vt100 terminal accepting user input and esc codes (colors, bel, cursor movement ..)
>   **Run them at boot-up** and/or on network status change possibility.
>   Schedule at selected time. (cron jobs)

Alternatively, [Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tasker/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) can be used as well to execute scripts (and other tasks) at certain events – as, e.g., on boot.