# It seems my device doesn't have init.d support, but I have a bunch of init.* files. Can I use the same approach somehow?

Tags: boot, init.d

```
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          3265 Jan  1  1970 init.class_main.sh
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          1730 Jan  1  1970 init.mdm.sh
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          3347 Jan  1  1970 init.mmi.boot.sh
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root           325 Jan  1  1970 init.mmi.dtv.sh
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root           562 Jan  1  1970 init.mmi.early_boot.sh
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          6341 Jan  1  1970 init.mmi.touch.sh
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          8592 Jan  1  1970 init.mmi.usb.sh
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          7054 Jan  1  1970 init.qcom.class_core.sh
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          6920 Jan  1  1970 init.qcom.early_boot.sh
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          6987 Jan  1  1970 init.qcom.sh
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          2962 Jan  1  1970 init.qcom.syspart_fixup.sh
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          2844 Jan  1  1970 init.rc
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          1327 Jan  1  1970 init.recovery.usb.rc
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root           683 Jan  1  1970 init.surnia.sh
```

These are all the files that begin with init.* in my `/`partition. In `/system/etc` I have some as well:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2767 Mar 26  2015 init.ath3k.bt.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1773 Mar 26  2015 init.crda.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4987 Mar 26  2015 init.qcom.audio.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          9938 Mar 26  2015 init.qcom.bt.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3651 Mar 26  2015 init.qcom.coex.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3791 Mar 26  2015 init.qcom.debug.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1725 Mar 26  2015 init.qcom.efs.sync.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3083 Mar 26  2015 init.qcom.fm.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4023 Mar 26  2015 init.qcom.modem_links.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         54877 Mar 26  2015 init.qcom.post_boot.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2767 Mar 26  2015 init.qcom.sdio.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         19105 Mar 26  2015 init.qcom.wifi.sh
```

Are these similar to the init.d feature? How can I check if these init.* are run at boot? If so, how can I use this structure to add a custom script to run at boot?

Comment: You probably can't. Just because the files carry `init` in their names doesn't mean the device supports `init.d` – if it would, they'd rather be in `/system/etc/init.d` and not have the `init` in their names. If you want `init.d` support on a device not having it, check my list of [init.d](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_1054) apps :)

Comment: If I recall correctly, only the init.rc is executed at boot. I believe that, by further investigating the syntax, you could create a similar file, in the same location, that will have to be included by the init.rc. Please keep in mind that I never tested what I said.

Comment: I did a quick test. What I did, was to create a little file (**init.dms.rc**), which was meant to create a blank text file on **/data** by using **touch**. I then included the file into the main **init.rc**, with the syntax */include /init.dms.rc*. After the reboot, not only had the blank file not been created, but all of my modifications (inclusion into **init.rc** and the whole **init.dms.rc**) were reverted.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "easy way" in my scenario. My search found so far plenty of options:

Related: [How can I run a script on boot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/how-can-i-run-a-script-on-boot)

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287540

http://iamcmotc.blogspot.com.br/2015/04/android-how-to-run-script-or-system.html

Repacking boot images to add custom scripts: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=443994

Boot process: http://bootloader.wikidot.com/linux:boot:android

The simpler way is to use an APK to emulate init.d: https://github.com/Androguide/Universal-init.d or https://github.com/Grarak/KernelAdiutor