# Modify AOSP to run a specific shell command on boot in Android 6.0

Tags: boot, aosp

I am trying to modify AOSP to run a specific shell command on boot.

I tried to modify `init.rc` in `system/core/rootdir/` to run a command on boot, but I could not make it work.

I know that I should use exec so I tried all these variations but none of them worked for me:

```
exec mkdir /data/local/tmp/test_directory
exec "mkdir /data/local/tmp/test_directory2"
exec -- mkdir /data/local/tmp/test_directory3
exec -- "mkdir /data/local/tmp/test_directory4"
```

I also tried all solutions on [this page on Android 6.0](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/how-can-i-run-a-script-on-boot) without any luck.

Anybody have an idea about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should grab the source code, modify `init.rc` and recompile it. The rootfs in Android gets 'refreshed' every time the device boots, so it makes no sense to edit `init.rc`directly on your device.
However there are alternative approaches and the following one is what I'm currently using.
Find a system service that you probably don't need at all, which in most times, is `debuggerd`. Locate its binary at `/system/bin/debuggerd`, rename it to something like `debuggerd.bak`, and then put your shell script in that place. Then in a shell, run

```
start debuggerd
```

and reboot. Your shell script will be executed every 5 seconds after the previous task died. It's recommended that you add a sleep loop at the bottom of your script if you want it to be run only once per boot.