# LineageOS: run custom script (start service) at boot

Tags: root-access, boot, scripts, lineageos

Seems like a simple thing. How can I run custom script on my (rooted) android with LineageOS at boot?

Neither creating it as `/data/local/userinit.d/99sshd` nor `/data/local/userinit.sh` did not help.

The LineageOS actually states in [`/etc/init.d/20userinit` that it will run `/data/local/userinit.sh` if exists](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/6560/217543), but according to `logcat` it does not.

The script (in my case) runs SSH daemon, which runs fine when I execute the script manually.

Comment: AFAIK init.d support still has to enabled externally. It was once pre-enabled, but somewhere along the timeline they cancelled it. There are apps on Play that would do this.