# How to run an Android init service with superuser SELinux context?

Tags: root-access, linux, scripts, services, init.d

I want to run an Android `init` service. I have a device which has rooted shell (purchased from manufacture as rooted). This device doesn't have Magisk or other su manager but `adb shell` is rooted and it has `userdebug` ROM installed on it.

I have followed following steps to set up `init` service:

1. Created `/etc/init/custom.rc` file with following contents:

```
#/etc/init/custom.rc

# define service, use executable here if script not needed
service custom /system/bin/custom.sh

    # don't start unless explicitly asked to
    disabled

    # run with unrestricted SELinux context to avoid avc denials
    # can also use "u:r:su:s0" on userdebug / eng builds if no Magisk
    # it's required if SELinux is enforcing and service needs access
    # to some system resources not allowed by default sepolicy
    # seclabel u:r:magisk:s0
    seclabel u:r:su:s0

# start the service when boot is completed
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    start custom
```

2. Created `/system/bin/custom.sh` with following contents:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

# execute the binary, should run in foreground, otherwise get in loop
echo "$(date): Starting program..."
exec /system/bin/executable
```

3. Placed my executable at `/system/bin/executable`.
4. Gave permissions to all files as following:

```
# Give rights to the executable
chown 0.0 /system/bin/executable
chmod 554 /system/bin/executable
chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 /system/bin/executable

# Give rights to the custom.sh
chown 0.0 /system/bin/custom.sh
chmod 554 /system/bin/custom.sh
chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 /system/bin/custom.sh

# Give rights to the custom.rc
chown 0.0 /etc/init/custom.rc
chmod 644 /etc/init/custom.rc
chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 /etc/init/custom.rc
```

5. Reboot the system.

I got following error:

```
[   55.829099 / 06-09 23:51:09.279][0] init: cannot execve('/system/bin/custom.sh'): Permission denied
[   55.850172 / 06-09 23:51:09.309][6] init: Service 'custom' (pid 7729)
[   55.850224 / 06-09 23:51:09.309][6] init: Service 'custom' (pid 7729) exited with status 127
[   55.850243 / 06-09 23:51:09.309][6] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'custom' (pid 7729) process group...
[   60.830224 / 06-09 23:51:14.289][6] init: starting service 'custom'...
[   60.832073 / 06-09 23:51:14.289][1] init: cannot execve('/system/bin/custom.sh'): Permission denied
[   60.832153 / 06-09 23:51:14.289][3] audit: type=1400 audit(1560142274.289:131): avc:  denied  { transition } for  pid=8035 comm="init" path="/system/bin/custom.sh" dev="sda24" ino=8146 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:r:su:s0 tclass=process permissive=0
```

I have very little experience with SELinux Policies. Please guide me how can I fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here the error is:

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1560142274.289:131): avc: denied { transition } for pid=8035 comm="init" path="/system/bin/custom.sh" dev="sda24" ino=8146 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:r:su:s0 tclass=process permissive=0
```

In easy words it states that *`init` is running with its context `u:r:init:0`, you want it to execute `/system/bin/custom.sh` with context `u:r:su:s0`, but it's not allowed in sepolicy*.

Rooting a phone gets two things: UID `0` (which you have) and an unrestricted SELinux context (which you don't have). Magisk allows any other context to do anything with its own contexts (`u:r:magisk:s0` and `u:object_r:magisk:s0`). And it can do anything to any other context. See details in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526).

`u:r:su:s0` is a limited context which doesn't allow `init` to make transition to itself. Only adb can do this on `userdebug` or `eng` builds of a ROM. See [reference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-9.0.0_r42/private/adbd.te#12) and [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207902/218526) for details.

Possible solutions:

- Run service in `init`'s context if it doesn't need to access any resources which `init` isn't allowed to access. But in most cases it's highly unlikely.
- Root your device with Magisk and run service with `u:r:magisk:s0` context as explained in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526).
- Modify your SELinux policy to allow this transition. Inject the following statement to `sepolicy` using [magiskpolicy](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/tools.html#magiskpolicy) or [sepolicy-inject](https://github.com/xmikos/setools-android/blob/master/README.md#usage):

  ```
  ~# magiskpolicy --live 'allow init su process transition'
  ~# sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p transition -l
  ```

  Also see `dmesg` for any other denials. As a reference, on my device `init` is allowed to do following operations to Magisk:

  ```
  allow init magisk : process { fork transition sigchld sigkill sigstop signull signal ptrace getsched setsched getsession getpgid setpgid getcap setcap share getattr setexec setfscreate noatsecure siginh setrlimit rlimitinh dyntransition setcurrent execmem execstack execheap setkeycreate setsockcreate getrlimit }
  allow init magisk : fifo_file { read write getattr open }
  allow init magisk : fd use
  allow init magisk : unix_stream_socket { getopt connectto }
  allow init magisk : binder { impersonate call set_context_mgr transfer }
  ```

  Then extract `boot.img` and `ramdisk` (only on non-[system-as-root](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/system-as-root) devices), replace `/sepolicy` with new policy file copied from `/sys/fs/selinux/policy`, repack `boot.img` and flash back.
- Set SELinux permissive

  From root `adb shell` do `echo -n 0 >/sys/fs/selinux/enforce` or `setenforce 0`. However this is not permanent and will be set to `enforced` on boot. `init` can't set it permissive. Also setting SELinux permissive is a security risk and hence never recommended.