# How to make SELinux injected rules persistent without unpacking-packing boot.img?

Tags: root-access, linux, services, selinux, init.d

I am working on an application that needs root access and I have a device which is rooted but not with Magisk. This device has only `adb shell` root available. So, I need an alternative to call the required functionality without the use of Magisk or other tools. I did it by placing my executable inside system directory and run it as a daemon. This daemon required access on some location which is restricted by SELinux policies.

I have injected the required policy with following commands:

```
    sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p transition -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t system_file -c file -p entrypoint -l
    sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p rlimitinh -l
    sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p siginh -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t shell_exec -c file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t shell_exec -c file -p execute -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t shell_exec -c file -p getattr  -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t vendor_toolbox_exec -c file -p execute_no_trans -l
    sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p noatsecure -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p getattr -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p execute -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t system_file -c file -p execute_no_trans -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t storage_file -c dir -p search -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t storage_file -c lnk_file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t tmpfs -c dir -p search -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t mnt_user_file -c dir -p search -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t mnt_user_file -c lnk_file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c dir -p search -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p append -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p open -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p write -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p open -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t media_rw_data_file -c file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t media_rw_data_file -c file -p write -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t media_rw_data_file -c file -p open -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t media_rw_data_file -c file -p append -l
```

The problem is that they are not persistent after reboot. I know I can extract boot.img and ramdisk, replace /sepolicy with new policy file copied from /sys/fs/selinux/policy, repack boot.img and flash back.

I want to do it without reflashing `boot.img`. Is there any way with which I can execute above commands after Android finishes with generating SELinux files?

I have tried following rc files:

```
#/etc/init/custom.rc

# define service, use executable here if script not needed
service custom /system/bin/custom.sh

    # don't start unless explicitly asked to
    disabled

    # Use `seclabel u:r:magisk:s0` to run with unrestricted SELinux context to avoid avc denials
    # can also use "u:r:su:s0" on userdebug / eng builds if no Magisk
    # it's required if SELinux is enforcing and service needs access
    # to some system resources not allowed by default sepolicy
    seclabel u:r:su:s0

# start the service when boot is completed
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p transition -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t system_file -c file -p entrypoint -l
    sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p rlimitinh -l
    sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p siginh -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t shell_exec -c file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t shell_exec -c file -p execute -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t shell_exec -c file -p getattr  -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t vendor_toolbox_exec -c file -p execute_no_trans -l
    sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p noatsecure -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p getattr -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p execute -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t system_file -c file -p execute_no_trans -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t storage_file -c dir -p search -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t storage_file -c lnk_file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t tmpfs -c dir -p search -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t mnt_user_file -c dir -p search -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t mnt_user_file -c lnk_file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c dir -p search -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p append -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p open -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p write -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p open -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t media_rw_data_file -c file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t media_rw_data_file -c file -p write -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t media_rw_data_file -c file -p open -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t media_rw_data_file -c file -p append -l
    start custom
```

but it is not working because I think Android generates SELinux files after my custom service has been triggered.

Also tried above commands on `onrestart` option of init service but failed.

Any suggestion?

Comment: if timing is your only problem i would suggest sleep command

Comment: I have tried to add 5 minutes sleep with `sleep 300` after `on property:sys.boot_completed=1` but the service is started instantly on boot complete so this command is not working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `init` service you have defined won't inject SELinux policy rules because of two reasons:

- The syntax of `sepolicy-inject` commands is incomplete; `.rc` files aren't shell scripts. The [correct syntax](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md#commands) would be:

  ```
  #/etc/init/custom.rc

  ...

  on property:sys.boot_completed=1
      exec - -- /system/bin/sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p transition -l

  ...
  ```
- This will execute the statement with context `u:r:init.s0`. But modifying SELinux policy requires permission `load_policy` i.e. you need to inject rule `sepolicy-inject -s init -t kernel -c security -p load_policy -l` which again won't be allowed to `init`. Read [What sepolicy context will allow any other context to access it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209374/218526) to know how SELinux is enforced on Android.

So you are in the same *chicken or the egg* situation as you were at the start of your [previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214839/218526). SELinux policy can only be modified with context `u:r:su:s0` which is available only through `adb shell` on `userdebug` builds of ROMs. Or root the device e.g. with Magisk, or replace `/sepolicy` file in `boot.img`.

**NOTE:** You don't need to define rules like `sepolicy-inject -s su ...` as `u:r:su:s0` is already [set permissive](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-9.0.0_r45/private/su.te#19) in policy.

**`sepolicy` File Locations:**

On pre-Treble Android releases, there are [two possible locations](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libselinux/+/refs/tags/android-7.1.2_r33/src/android.c#56) defined for `sepolicy` file:

```
/sepolicy
/data/security/current/sepolicy
```

As stated [here](https://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_SEforAndroid_1#SELinux_Policy_Files):

> The Android initialisation / reload process will first check for this file at: `/data/security/current/sepolicy`. If not present then check root directory: `/sepolicy`.

However `sepolicy` is loaded by `init` at very early boot process when `/data` is not mounted. As stated [here](https://hub.packtpub.com/booting-system/):

> Since only the root filesystem is mounted, it chooses `/sepolicy` at this time. The other path is for dynamic runtime reloads of policy.

So initially `/sepolicy` is loaded for sure. But you can put modified `sepolicy` at other locations to see if the previous policy is (or could possibly be) overwritten at some later boot stage. You might need to copy other files as well; [this post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=70470509&postcount=55) could be helpful. I never tried this.

On Oreo+ a monolithic policy is loaded from `/sepolicy` if the device is not a Treble device (or if Magisk [patched](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/v19.3/native/jni/init/rootfs.cpp#L51) `init` to force load `/sepolicy`). On Treble devices `/system`, `/vendor` and `/odm` are mounted by kernel before starting `init`, as configured in DTB. Here a pre-compiled split policy is loaded from `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` if it matches with `/system`, or the policy is built from `.cil` files in `/system/etc/selinux` and `/vendor/etc/selinux` before loading. See details [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/init/selinux.cpp#24).

In both situations things are far more complicated to try than simply replacing `/sepolicy` file in `boot.img`, which is not a big deal in my opinion. You can `dd` out a backup of your original `boot.img` to `/sdcard` which can be restored in a few seconds anytime. However bootloader needs to be unlocked to boot a modified `boot.img`.
Please note that on devices with [system-as-root](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/system-as-root) (`A/B` or others) `ramdisk` is moved to `system.img`. So all files which were previously part of `boot.img` (except kernel and DTB) are now part of `system` partition.

Comment: Thanks for excellent knowledge. Now, I am trying to pack/unpack boot.img and facing a problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425339/isuue-in-repacking-boot-img-with-mkbootimg-tools Can you help in this?

Comment: I got a device with userdebug ROM that has split device policies to support treble but I am not able to patch the required policies. Please help in identify the problem: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218911/how-to-add-selinux-policy-on-a-user-debug-rom-that-has-split-policy-scheme

Answer (score 2):

I know the question was asked quite some time ago, but since I tried doing something similar recently and this post was one of the top hits on Google, I want to share my recent experience to help others.

*Note that this answer will focus solely on Android 9 to 13 and Treble devices.*

If we want to know how to modify the SELinux policies, I believe it is good to first understand how the policies are loaded in the first place.

**SELinux in the boot process**

At an early stage of the Android boot process and after mounting most of the partitions, `init` will attempt to load the SELinux policies from a monolithic sepolicy file found at either `/odm/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` or `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy`. If `init` notices that the device is updated out of sync, `init` will instead recompile the SELinux policies based on `.cil` files that can be found on several locations.

You can find all the details in the comments of the [init/selinux.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/heads/android11-release/init/selinux.cpp) source file and by looking at the implementation, but here is a summary of the exact steps taken by `init`:

1. Find the sepolicy file to use:

   - if `/odm/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` exists, use it as the sepolicy file to use
   - else, if `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` exists, use it as the sepolicy file to use
   - else if neither of the above exists, stop here, recompile the policies based on the `.cil` files and load the newly compiled sepolicy file.
2. Check if device was updated out of sync:

   - Compare `/(odm|vendor)/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy.plat_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256` and `/system/etc/selinux/plat_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256`
   - Compare `/(odm|vendor)/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy.system_ext_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256` and `/system_ext/etc/selinux/system_ext_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256`
   - Compare `/(odm|vendor)/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy.product_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256` and `/product/etc/selinux/product_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256`
   - (On Android 13) Compare `/(odm|vendor)/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy.apex_sepolicy.sha256` and `/dev/selinux/apex_sepolicy.sha256`
   - if any of the above pair of files do not match, stop here, recompile the policies based on the `.cil` files and load the newly compiled sepolicy file.
3. If everything is ok, load the precompiled sepolicy file (`/odm/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` or `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy`)

The compilation of the policies based on the `.cil` files is as follows:

1. Get the latest version of the policies that are compatible with the `vendor` version (`/vendor/etc/selinux/plat_sepolicy_vers.txt`, note that `init` does not look at the file in the `/odm` partition)
2. Gather the `.cil` files to compile:

   - `/system/etc/selinux/mapping/{vendor_version}.cil`
   - `/system/etc/selinux/mapping/{vendor_version}.compat.cil`
   - `/system_ext/etc/selinux/system_ext_sepolicy.cil`
   - `/system_ext/etc/selinux/mapping/{vendor_version}.cil`
   - `/product/etc/selinux/product_sepolicy.cil`
   - `/product/etc/selinux/mapping/{vendor_version}.cil`
   - `/vendor/etc/selinux/plat_pub_versioned.cil`
   - `/vendor/etc/selinux/vendor_sepolicy.cil` or if it does not exist: `/vendor/etc/selinux/nonplat_sepolicy.cil`
   - `/odm/etc/selinux/odm_sepolicy.cil`
3. Compile the above files with `secilc` to `/dev/sepolicy.XXXXXX`
4. Load policies from `/dev/sepolicy.XXXXXX`

**Modifying SELinux policies permantently**

Now that we understand how `init` loads the policies, it is easy to see how one could permanently add new policies to the system:

- Directly add the policies to `/odm/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` or `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` with `sepolicy-inject`:

  ```
  sepolicy-inject -s su -t system_file -c file -p entrypoint -P /vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy -o /vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy
  ```
- Make `init` thinks the device is updated out of sync (By modifying one of the above `.sha256` files, or deleting the precompiled sepolicy files) and modify one of the above `.cil` files

Note that in both cases, you will need to have a read-write access to the partition you want to modify (`/vendor`, `/odm`, and/or `/system`). These partitions are normally mounted as read-only, so you will have to either:

- Remount them as read-write if you have root access (either because your device is rooted, or using `adb root` on a `userdebug` Android build)
- Boot in recovery mode, mount the partitions as read-write and modify them in recovery

  - [This update-package template](https://github.com/Alhyoss/android-flashable-zip) I made may interest you there

If you do not want to have to remount the partitions every time you want to change the SELinux policies, you can add some SELinux rules to allow `init` to load new policies, thereby resolving the chicken and egg problem (as mentioned in [this excellent answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215010/how-to-make-selinux-injected-rules-persistent-without-unpacking-packing-boot-img/215395#215395)) you had with your `init` script. You can find which SELinux rules are needed by searching for SELinux violations (avc errors) in the device logs on startup:

```
adb logcat | grep avc
```

With this, you will be able to have an `init` script that loads new policies with `sepolicy-inject`.