# How to make SELinux permissive with `systemless-root` on a `system-as-root device`?

Tags: root-access, rom-flashing, linux, aosp, systemless-root

I have a Samsung S10 5G device that is actually a `system-as-root` device. I have rooted it by following the instructions given [here](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#samsung-system-as-root).

As the `system-as-root` devices have no `ramdisk` in `boot.img` but in `recovery.img` so, I have to always boot the device with a recovery combination to get the root access.

I have an app that requires some SELinux policies to work. I have injected them with the help of `sepolicy-inject` using following commands:

```
    sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p transition -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t system_file -c file -p entrypoint -l
    sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p rlimitinh -l
    sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p siginh -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t shell_exec -c file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t shell_exec -c file -p execute -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t shell_exec -c file -p getattr  -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t vendor_toolbox_exec -c file -p execute_no_trans -l
    sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p noatsecure -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p getattr -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p execute -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t system_file -c file -p execute_no_trans -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t storage_file -c dir -p search -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t storage_file -c lnk_file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t tmpfs -c dir -p search -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t mnt_user_file -c dir -p search -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t mnt_user_file -c lnk_file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c dir -p search -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p append -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p open -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p write -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p open -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t media_rw_data_file -c file -p read -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t media_rw_data_file -c file -p write -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t media_rw_data_file -c file -p open -l
    sepolicy-inject -s su -t media_rw_data_file -c file -p append -l
```

but after reboot, I need to run this command again as they are not persistent. I don't want to use a key combination on the device to use my app on the root mode of the device. So, I am searching for any way to inject them permanently.

I can think of the following solutions:

- Modify `init.rc` file of `system.img` to run these commands but when I have tried to modify `init.rc` with just adding a comment and flashed it on the device then that comment is lost. Don't know what happens. I have flashed it with all Odin files and within AP file. This AP file is patched by Magisk.
- Change the SELinux from enforcing to permissive. I am not sure how can I do it with either **root access** or **Modified ROM Flashing**.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

> I am searching for any way to inject them permanently.

As explained in my answer to your previous question: [How to make SELinux injected rules persistent without unpacking-packing boot.img?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215395/218526) you need to modify SELinux policy file in order to inject rules permanently.

Policy could either be monolithic (pre-compiled `sepolicy` file on `initramfs` or `/system` or `/vendor`) or split.

In latter case it can be either pre-compiled SEPolicy (`/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy`) or you need to compile it from `.cil` files in `/system/etc/selinux/` and `/vendor/etc/selinux/` using SEPolicy compiler (`/system/bin/secilc`).

In former case the hashes of both platform and non-platform policies (`/system/etc/selinux/plat_and_mapping_sepolicy.cil.sha256` and `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy.plat_and_mapping.sha256`) must match, otherwise `init` won't load it.

In either case you can't retain systemless approach.

> Modify `init.rc` file of `system.img` to run these commands but when I have tried to modify `init.rc` with just adding a comment and flashed it on the device then that comment is lost.

As explained in my answer to your previous question: [How to boot system-as-root device always as rooted?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218242/218526) on rooted SAR device `system.img` is mounted at `/system_root` by Magisk `init`, contents of `ramdisk` are then copied to `/` cleaning everything previously existing, files are added / modified in rootfs `/`, `/system_root/system` is bind-mounted to `/system`, and finally `[/system]/init` is executed for normal boot. So you need to edit `/system_root/init.rc` for permanent changes. Please note that modifying `system.img` (or `vendor.img`) would break `dm-verity` and OTAs.

> Change the SELinux from enforcing to permissive. I am not sure how can I do it with either **root access** or **Modified ROM Flashing**.

SELinux is set `enforcing` by `init` (if it's not already `enforcing`), so you need to modify `init` source. Or on `userdebug` ROMs pass `androidboot.selinux=permissive` kernel command-line parameter. For details see [What sepolicy context will allow any other context to access it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209374/218526)

With root access just execute the following in any `.rc` file:

```
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    exec u:r:magisk:s0 -- /system/bin/setenforce 0
```

For details see [How to fix SELinux “avc: denied” errors?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207647/218526)