# How to add SELinux policy on a user-debug ROM that has `split` policy scheme?

Tags: root-access, selinux, init.d

I have a Sony device that supports `treble` and is a `system-as-root` and `A/B` device. It has a user-debug ROM installed on it so, its adb shell is rooted.

I have disabled `dm-verity` using `adb disable-verity` after running `adb root` and `adb remount` commands.

As documented [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/init/selinux.cpp#24), this device also has `split` policies at `/system/etc/selinux`(the 'plat' portion of the policy) and `/vendor/etc/selinux`(the 'nonplat' portion of the policy).

I am trying to run `test.sh` using following init script:

```
#/etc/init/m_daemon.rc

# define service, use executable here if script not needed
service m_daemon /system/xbin/test.sh

    # don't start unless explicitly asked to
    disabled

    # Use `seclabel u:r:magisk:s0` to run with unrestricted SELinux context to avoid avc denials
    # can also use "u:r:su:s0" on userdebug / eng builds if no Magisk.
    # It's required if SELinux is enforcing and service needs access
    # to some system resources not allowed by default sepolicy
    # seclabel u:object_r:qlogd_exec:s0
    seclabel u:r:su:s0

# start the service when the boot is completed
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    # Use it to start the service
    start m_daemon
```

`/system/xbin/test.sh` file has the following contents:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
echo `date` > /sdcard/test
```

When the device reboot then it fails to run with the following error:

> [202.932913 / 11-26 20:21:04.074](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218913/how-to-extract-magiskpolicy-from-magiskinit64) audit: type=1400 audit(1574763664.074:213): avc:  denied  { transition } for  pid=8534 comm="init" path="/system/xbin/test.sh" dev="sda24" ino=8150 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:r:su:s0 tclass=process permissive=0
>
> [202.933268 / 11-26 20:21:04.074](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218913/how-to-extract-magiskpolicy-from-magiskinit64) init: cannot execve('/system/xbin/test.sh'): Permission denied

To fix it, I have used `sepolicy-inject` and run the following commands:

```
sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p transition -P /sys/fs/selinux/policy -l
sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p noatsecure -P /sys/fs/selinux/policy -l
sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p rlimitinh -P /sys/fs/selinux/policy -l
sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p siginh -P /sys/fs/selinux/policy -l
```

but these needs to be run again after reboot.

So, I have tried to patch `precompiled_sepolicy` using following commands:

```
sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p transition -P /vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy -l
sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p noatsecure -P /vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy -l
sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p rlimitinh -P /vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy -l
sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p siginh -P /vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy -l
```

but the policies are not injected: neither live nor after reboot.

To test, I am just checking the date in `/sdcard/test` file.

So, I just want to know:

- Why patching `precompiled_policy` didn't work?
- Where to patch the required policies using rooted adb shell that should persist after a reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To patch the policies, do the following:

1. Change the value in `/system/etc/selinux/plat_and_mapping_sepolicy.cil.sha256` OR empty this file.
2. Inject required policies in `/system/etc/selinux/plat_sepolicy.cil`
3. "Loading compiled SELinux policy" should show in logs and the init service will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

As I believe the answer answer your questions, here is a shameless copy/paste of my answer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215010/how-to-make-selinux-injected-rules-persistent-without-unpacking-packing-boot-img):

*Note that this answer will focus solely on Android 9 to 13 and Treble devices.*

If we want to know how to modify the SELinux policies, I believe it is good to first understand how the policies are loaded in the first place.

**SELinux in the boot process**

At an early stage of the Android boot process and after mounting most of the partitions, `init` will attempt to load the SELinux policies from a monolithic sepolicy file found at either `/odm/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` or `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy`. If `init` notices that the device is updated out of sync, `init` will instead recompile the SELinux policies based on `.cil` files that can be found on several locations.

You can find all the details in the comments of the [init/selinux.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/heads/android11-release/init/selinux.cpp) source file and by looking at the implementation, but here is a summary of the exact steps taken by `init`:

1. Find the sepolicy file to use:

   - if `/odm/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` exists, use it as the sepolicy file to use
   - else, if `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` exists, use it as the sepolicy file to use
   - else if neither of the above exists, stop here, recompile the policies based on the `.cil` files and load the newly compiled sepolicy file.
2. Check if device was updated out of sync:

   - Compare `/(odm|vendor)/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy.plat_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256` and `/system/etc/selinux/plat_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256`
   - Compare `/(odm|vendor)/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy.system_ext_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256` and `/system_ext/etc/selinux/system_ext_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256`
   - Compare `/(odm|vendor)/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy.product_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256` and `/product/etc/selinux/product_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256`
   - (On Android 13) Compare `/(odm|vendor)/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy.apex_sepolicy.sha256` and `/dev/selinux/apex_sepolicy.sha256`
   - if any of the above pair of files do not match, stop here, recompile the policies based on the `.cil` files and load the newly compiled sepolicy file.
3. If everything is ok, load the precompiled sepolicy file (`/odm/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` or `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy`)

The compilation of the policies based on the `.cil` files is as follows:

1. Get the latest version of the policies that are compatible with the `vendor` version (`/vendor/etc/selinux/plat_sepolicy_vers.txt`, note that `init` does not look at the file in the `/odm` partition)
2. Gather the `.cil` files to compile:

   - `/system/etc/selinux/mapping/{vendor_version}.cil`
   - `/system/etc/selinux/mapping/{vendor_version}.compat.cil`
   - `/system_ext/etc/selinux/system_ext_sepolicy.cil`
   - `/system_ext/etc/selinux/mapping/{vendor_version}.cil`
   - `/product/etc/selinux/product_sepolicy.cil`
   - `/product/etc/selinux/mapping/{vendor_version}.cil`
   - `/vendor/etc/selinux/plat_pub_versioned.cil`
   - `/vendor/etc/selinux/vendor_sepolicy.cil` or if it does not exist: `/vendor/etc/selinux/nonplat_sepolicy.cil`
   - `/odm/etc/selinux/odm_sepolicy.cil`
3. Compile the above files with `secilc` to `/dev/sepolicy.XXXXXX`
4. Load policies from `/dev/sepolicy.XXXXXX`

**Modifying SELinux policies permantently**

Now that we understand how `init` loads the policies, it is easy to see how one could permanently add new policies to the system:

- Directly add the policies to `/odm/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` or `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` with `sepolicy-inject`:

  ```
  sepolicy-inject -s su -t system_file -c file -p entrypoint -P /vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy -o /vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy
  ```
- Make `init` thinks the device is updated out of sync (By modifying one of the above `.sha256` files, or deleting the precompiled sepolicy files) and modify one of the above `.cil` files

Note that in both cases, you will need to have a read-write access to the partition you want to modify (`/vendor`, `/odm`, and/or `/system`). These partitions are normally mounted as read-only, so you will have to either:

- Remount them as read-write if you have root access (either because your device is rooted, or using `adb root` on a `userdebug` Android build)
- Boot in recovery mode, mount the partitions as read-write and modify them in recovery

  - [This update-package template](https://github.com/Alhyoss/android-flashable-zip) I made may interest you there

If you do not want to have to remount the partitions every time you want to change the SELinux policies, you can add some SELinux rules to allow `init` to load new policies, thereby resolving the chicken and egg problem (as mentioned in [this excellent answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215010/how-to-make-selinux-injected-rules-persistent-without-unpacking-packing-boot-img/215395#215395)) you had with your `init` script. You can find which SELinux rules are needed by searching for SELinux violations (avc errors) in the device logs on startup:

```
adb logcat | grep avc
```

With this, you will be able to have an `init` script that loads new policies with `sepolicy-inject`.