# How to extract `magiskpolicy` from `magiskinit64`?

Tags: linux, magisk

I have cloned the Magisk code at my Ubuntu machine. I have successfully run `build.py` and get the **Magisk.zip** file in Out directory. This zip contains `arm`, `chromeos`, `common`, `META-INF` and `x86` folders.

As documented [here](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/docs/tools.md). I should be able to get `magiskpolicy` using `./magiskinit64 -x magiskpolicy /system/` but this command is not working and neither giving any error. Similary `./magiskinit64 --help` is also not working.

```
1|flashlm:/system/magisk # ls
META-INF Magisk.tar arm chromeos common x86
flashlm:/system/magisk # getprop ro.product.cpu.abi
arm64-v8a
flashlm:/system/magisk # ./arm/magiskinit64 --help
1|flashlm:/system/magisk # ./arm/magiskinit64 -x magisk /system/magisk
1|flashlm:/system/magisk # ls
META-INF Magisk.tar arm chromeos common x86
flashlm:/system/magisk # ./arm/magiskinit64 -x magiskpolicy /system/magisk
1|flashlm:/system/magisk # ls
META-INF Magisk.tar arm chromeos common x86
flashlm:/system/magisk # ./arm/magiskinit -x magiskpolicy /system/magisk
1|flashlm:/system/magisk # ls
META-INF Magisk.tar arm chromeos common x86
flashlm:/system/magisk # ./arm/magiskinit --help
1|flashlm:/system/magisk # ls
META-INF Magisk.tar arm chromeos common x86
flashlm:/system/magisk # ls -l -Z ./arm/*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root u:object_r:system_file:s0 533856 2019-11-26 17:42 ./arm/magiskboot
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root u:object_r:system_file:s0 617216 2019-11-26 17:42 ./arm/magiskinit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root u:object_r:system_file:s0 596736 2019-11-26 17:42 ./arm/magiskinit64
```

Any suggestions about what I have missed?

Comment: wrong architecture? according to the path ./arm/magiskinit64 i guess you try to execute arm64 binary on x86_64 cpu (ubuntu machine)?

Comment: I am trying on the `arm64-v8a` android device. My understanding is that it has arm64 architecture and so trying to run `magiskinit64`. I have tried it on two `arm64-v8a` devices but I didn't get any result.

Comment: Also, `magiskboot` is working fine on the same android device.