# init: cannot execve('/system/bin/custom.sh'): Permission denied

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, linux, aosp, systemless-root

I have a [rooted system-as-root](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#samsung-system-as-root) Samsung Device and I am trying to run an init service which runs `custom.sh` script using `u:r:su:s0` SELinux context.

```
# define service, use executable here if script not needed
service custom /system/bin/custom.sh

    # don't start unless explicitly asked to
    disabled

    # Use `seclabel u:r:magisk:s0` to run with unrestricted SELinux context to avoid avc denials
    # can also use "u:r:su:s0" on userdebug / eng builds if no Magisk.
    # It's required if SELinux is enforcing and service needs access
    # to some system resources not allowed by default sepolicy
    seclabel u:r:su:s0

# start the service when boot is completed
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    # Use it to start the service
    start custom
```

As per my understanding, the rules for transition from `init` context to `su` context is not defined so, I should get `avc: denial` error.

But, I am getting permission denied error as following:

> init: cannot execve('/system/bin/custom.sh'): Permission denied

I have checked the permission of `custom.sh` file and it is as following:

> -r-xr-xr-- 1 root root 153 2019-11-04 13:25 /system/custom.sh

Please suggest what is happening here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As evident from [`init` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r49/init/service.cpp#923):

```
...
static bool ExpandArgsAndExecv(const std::vector<std::string>& args) {
    ...
    return execv(c_strings[0], c_strings.data()) == 0;
}
...
        if (!ExpandArgsAndExecv(args_)) {
            PLOG(ERROR) << "cannot execve('" << args_[0] << "')";
        }
```

For whatever reason if `init` fails to execute the script `custom.sh` (i.e. syscall `execve` returns non-zero exit code), you will get `cannot execve` error. `Permission denied (EACCES)` is returned by [`execve`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) in multiple situations e.g. unable to read file path, no `+x` permission on binary or filesystem mounted with `noexec`. Inability to `read`|`open`|`execute` script or make context transition is returned as `EACCES`.

Also `cannot execve` is logged by `init` but `avc: denied` is logged by SELinux subsystem through `audit` subsystem or kernel logging. You should get both errors in `dmesg` or `logcat -b events` or `logcat -b kernel`. If you don't, may be there is a `dontaudit` rule defined for source or target or both contexts.

> Please suggest what is happening here and how can I fix it?

As explained in my answer to your previous question: [How to run an Android init service with superuser SELinux context?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214866/218526) define SELinux rules to allow `init` read / execute `custom.sh` script and make transition to `u:r:su:s0`.

Comment: I didn't find any `avc: denied` error for `custom.sh`. The only error I can see with `dmesg | grep avc:` is `avc:  denied  { find } ..` but I get your point and my understanding is: It should be fixed by injecting the required SELinux permission. Thanks.