# (Semi) permanently disable touch input

Tags: adb, lineageos, touchscreen

I own a Samsung Galaxy S4 (GT-I9515L "jfvelte") running Lineage OS 16. It has a broken touchscreen which register random "ghost" touches.

I'm able to use it with the help of a USB mouse. To disable the touchscreen I use `adb` to open a shell on `/dev/input` and remove `event3`, which disables the touchscreen (renaming or moving the file doesn't work, only removing it) - until reboot.

How do I keep it disabled even after reboot? Preferably, I'd like a way that I can enable it later if I ever want to.

Answer (score 1):

Turn's out there's [`init.sh` support](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/6560/22441) on Lineage (content of `/etc/init.d/90userinit`):

```
#!/system/bin/sh
# call userinit.sh if present in /data/local

if [ -e /data/local/userinit.sh ];
then
   log -p i -t userinit "Executing /data/local/userinit.sh";
   /system/bin/sh /data/local/userinit.sh;
   setprop lineage.userinit.active 1;
fi;
```

So I wrote a bash script that removes the `/dev/input/event3` on boot, thus It disabling touch input on boot time:

`/data/local/userinit.sh`:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
rm /dev/input/event3
```

If I ever need to re-enable touch input, I can simply remove the bash script.