# How to disable automount of /dev/block/mmcblk1p2?

Tags: mount, app2sd, link2sd, sd-ext

I installed link2sd then formatted my 2nd partition as ext2. Then I used link2sd to create mount script. Now,due to free version i'm unable to link internal data to this partition. So i removed the link2sd app from my device. But the problem is even after uninstalling the app, a unmount command and a restart the /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 is still getting mounted after reboot.
How can I fix this? Where does this auto mount script located ?
Note 1: I tried removing install script located at /data/data/com.buak.link2sd/files. But still the partition is getting mounted automatically.

Comment: Remove the init.d script

Comment: Can you specify the location of `init.d` file?

Comment: See https://duckduckgo.com/?q=link2sd+init.d+script and https://duckduckgo.com/?q=where+are+android+init.d+scripts+saved. Also see my answers to https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217265/218526 and https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526

Comment: I tried the following: 1.removed link2sd
2. mount -o rw,remount /system
3. edited /system/bin/debuggerd and removed mount related lines 
4. reboot... still 2nd partition is mouted at /data/sdext2

Comment: */su/su.d/11link2sd* or */data/adb/service.d/11link2sd*

Comment: Thanks. In my case , the script was there in `/data/adb/services.d/11link2sd`. I moved that file to some place to keep it as backup, unmounted the /data/sdext2 manually and performed a reboot... Now, it's not mounted... thanx @alecxs