# How to Autostart App on Android TV

Tags: linux, boot

I'm using an Amlogic TV Box with Android 9.

I'm trying to get an app to launch at startup, but the app will not launch.

---

The method I'm using is:

`/data/local/userinit.sh`

```
#!/system/bin/sh
am start com.package.name
```

or

```
#!/system/bin/sh
am start com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

---

This version of Android does not have the Auto-start manager in settings to do it the easy way.

Comment: You need to wait for the Android's Zygote process which starts app processes, and SystemUI app which shows notifications and status bar at top, and preferably Home/Launcher app which show app icons, to come up before executing that command.

Comment: Also see my answers to [How can I run a script on boot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217265/218526) and [How to run an executable on boot and keep it running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526).